# C# HttpClient fails to open connection

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a WPF application using HttpClient to connect to Mongoose webserver. The HttpClient code does not always establish a TCP connection to the WebServer when getAsync() method is invoked (as observed from WireShark). Looking at the webserver end there is no activity, which reflects the WireShark result. 
To make debugging easy I have placed the HttpClient code in a simple method.

```
    public void doGet()
    {
        HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();
        wc.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        wc.BaseAddress = new Uri("HTTP://192.168.2.249:8080");

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> t = wc.GetAsync("/rest/clients");
        t.ContinueWith(this.wc_OpenReadCompleted);
    }

    protected void wc_OpenReadCompleted(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> p)
    {
    }
```

If I run the doGet method a couple of times the connection will be established and then it will always work. If I shutdown the application and restart it, the problem will repeat until a connection is established.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using async/await?

Comment: All sorts of reasons why someone can't use async/await, but it doesn't really apply to the question.